# Meteor android apk showing blank white screen

Tags: android, angularjs, meteor, ionic-framework

I have built a meteor app it's successfully working on web but when i built it's apk file it's showing only white screen. I have also signed the apk command i run "meteor build ~/Chat-App --server=chat.citze.in"
any help please I am stuck here.

here is my mobile-config js

```
 App.info({
  id: 'com.example.chat.citze',
  name: 'Chat',
  description: 'Citze Chat Application',
  author: 'Himanshu Gupta',
  email: 'contact@example.com',
  website: 'http://chat.citze.in'

});

// Set PhoneGap/Cordova preferences
App.setPreference('BackgroundColor', '0xff0000ff');
App.setPreference('HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar', true);
App.setPreference('Orientation', 'default');
App.setPreference('Orientation', 'all', 'ios');
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Are you using any plugins? Have you set the right access permissions for the app?

Comment: I am not using any plugin and where I have to set permissions for the app..?

Answer (score 1):

Could be you need internet permission or similar for your android app, also could be a signature problem of the apk.

Have a look at your AndroidManifest.xml

For permissions you at least will need the internet permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

This might also be helpful:

https://forums.meteor.com/t/cordova-is-it-possible-to-force-meteor-to-use-https-for-meteor-local/17908/5

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-set-geolocation-permissions-for-android/11616

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> This permission is also set I have found an article that we s<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />hould remove ng-app from main.html giving it a try

Comment: I have tried it now receiving error 
"The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://meteor.local' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'http://localhost:12912' is therefore not allowed access."  any solution

Comment: where is that header located? you are supplying two different values to that one. you need to find out where they are...

Comment: Could you please explain me in which file I have to set header because so fat I tried
Meteor.startup(function() {
  console.log('Configuring content-security-policy:');
  BrowserPolicy.content.allowSameOriginForAll();
  BrowserPolicy.content.allowOriginForAll('http://meteor.local');
  BrowserPolicy.content.allowOriginForAll('https://192.168.0.104:3000');
  BrowserPolicy.content.allowOriginForAll('https://*.yourapp.io');
  BrowserPolicy.content.allowOriginForAll('https://*.stripe.com');
  BrowserPolicy.content.allowEval();
  BrowserPolicy.framing.disallow();
});

Comment: and in mobile config I set 
 App.accessRule("*");

but no result

Comment: like the error says: you have a file called "meteor.local" and it seems "localhost:12912" in both of these files you are supplying different values for the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header which is a problem.